# How to show the symplectic group is a submanifold of $GL(n,\mathbb{H})$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to show that the symplectic group $Sp(n) =\{A\in GL(n,\mathbb{H})\mid \overline{A}^TA=I\}$ is a regular submanifold of $GL(n,\mathbb{H})$ but I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that the map $f:M\to M$ from the space $M$ of square matrices of size $n$ to itself such that $f(A)=\overline A^tA$ has I as a regular value. To do this,, you need to compute the rank of its differential at all $A$ in the sympectic group.

Let us compute the differential of $f$ at a matrix $A$, which is a real linear map $Df_A:M\to M$ such that 
\begin{align}
Df_A(B)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(A+hB)-f(A)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(\bar A+h\bar B)^t(A+hB)-\bar A^tA}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h\bar A^tB+h\bar B^tA+h^2\bar B^tB}{h}\\
&=\bar A^tB+\bar B^tA
\end{align}
Notice that for all $A$ and $B$ we have $Df_A(B)=Df_I(\bar A^tB)$. It follows that the differential $Df_A:M\to M$ is the composition of the linear map $X\in\mapsto \bar A^tB\in M$, which is an ismorphism if $A$ is in the symplctic group, and $Df_I$. In particular, the rank of the linear map $Df_A$ is equal to the rank of $Df_I$ whenever $A$ is in the symplectic group.

You should now be able to compute the rank of the map $Df_I:B\in M\mapsto B+\bar B^t\in M$.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have 50 points, so I cannot make a comment. The usual strategy is to show that the symplectic group is the  preimage of a regular value, then use the regular value theorem.

Comment: The symplectic group is the kernel of a linear map?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Let me rewrite.

Comment: But actually, isn't Sp(n) the kernel of $\overline AA^T -I $ ?

Comment: Well, that is not a linear map nor a group homomorphism.

Comment: O.K, it is an affine map, and so Sp(n) is just the zero set. I guess that doesn't buy much towards showing it is a submanifold.

Comment: I don't know what an affine map is, but I would guess it is not an affine map, either...

Comment: An affine map is a composition of a linear map and a translation. But we have a product, which screws up linearity. Never mind.

Comment: But I'm still surprised at the fact that you can guess it is not an affine map when you don't have a working definition.

Comment: Well, I know many thing which are affine, and none of them can be quadratic, and this map is quadratic.

Comment: Actually, you're right that is not affine, because there is a multiplication involved, but I don't know if by quadratic you mean that there are terms that are squared: $(A+A')(B^T+B'^T)=AB^T+AB'^T +A'B^T+A'B'^T$ , so no terms is multiplied by itself. Where I was wrong is that multiplying is not linear.

Comment: At any rate, my mistake, the map is neither linear nor affine. My bad.

Comment: WHat I mean is that the entries of the matrix $A^tA-I$ are quadratic polynomials of the entries of the matrix $A$.